# how to print png chart from google charteditor?

Tags: html, django, charts, google-visualization

From the official documentation of Google charts, It provides the following syntac for getting the imageURI() for a specific chart type:

```
 var my_div = document.getElementById('chart_div');
 var chart = new google.visualization.ChartType(chart_div);

 google.visualization.events.addListener(my_chart, 'ready', function () {
    var imgUri = chart.getImageURI();
    //perform print function
 });
```

However I am using [Google's chart editor method](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#charteditor), and I am unable to retrieve the imageURI for the chart selected.

```
  chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();

   google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'ready', function () {
      var imgUri = chartEditor.getChart().getImageURI();
      //throws error: getChart().getImageURI() not a function of chartEditor
   });
```

I am particularly new to the usage of Chart editor function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the [ChartEditor class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_5) does not have a method for `getChart()`

but it can return a `ChartWrapper` --> `getChartWrapper()`

`ChartWrapper` has a method for --> `getChart()`

so to get the image...

```
chartEditor.getChartWrapper().getChart().getImageURI();
```